# php laravel image tags

Tags: php, laravel, tags

Well I'm working with Laravel and tags as the title says and my problem is the following.

I have an Image Library where every image has a Tag. The relationship is many to many from both sides.Everything works fine except one thing. When I browse to my media Library, all images are printed there and I want also to print all the tags that the Image is related to. Through Eloquent I can print the tags but thing is that the id of every image is needed to print correctly the related tags.

My Image repository is the above where the imageId is hardcoded. From repo I pass it to controller and then to a view with a foreach loop.

```
$result = new StdClass;
$result->items = $images->skip($offset)->take($limit)->get();
$collection = new Collection($result->items);

    $ImageId =$collection->get(2)->media_library_id;
    $image = $this->media->find($ImageId);

    $tags = $image->tags()->get();
    $result->tags = $tags;
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your initial image query or model, but you can use with() to eager-load the tags.

```
$images = Image::with('tags')
    ->skip($offset)
    ->take($limit)
    ->get();
```

Then in your template you should just be able to use something like

```
@foreach ($images as $image)
    <img src="{{ $image->src }}" alt="">
    @foreach ($image->tags as $tag)
        {{ $tag->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot the initial Image query. Eager loading would have work but I use a raw query to grab the images.     $images = $this->db->table('media_library_image_info')
            ->leftJoin('media_library_images', 'media_library_images.media_library_image_info_id', '=', 'media_library_image_info.media_library_image_info_id')
            ->select([
                'media_library_image_info.*',
                'media_library_images.path as thumbnail'